# Accessibility focus of childviews in nestedscrollview

Tags: android, accessibility

I have a problem with the accessibility focus of the `NestedScrollView` child views. Currently, the focus iteration during accessibility mode only iterates through the views where the views are visible on the screen.

Is there a layout configuration where I can set to scroll the NestedScrollview during focus iteration? Currently, the focus iteration just stops once it reaches the last visible view on the current screen and not scroll the `scrollview` to the next focusable view?

Tested with Android version 4.3(Galaxy nexus) and 5.1.1(Nexus 4). TalkBack version is 4.2.0. In the latest update, we also included testing within devices Android 5.1 V 22, Android 8 V 26, Android 10, V 29. Tested with the latest TalkBack version.

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsvScrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
  
    <!-- Any other views here. Including WebView -->
  
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**UPDATE.**

Somehow similar question for the TalkBack Accessibility Service. And setting Content Description for it. How we need to set up `View`s with `NestedScrollView` to make TalkBack iterate Screen Reader throw all items **with scrolling**. And not only visible pages. Please consider the explanation for scrolling WebView inside `NestedScrollView`. As it's also an important thing in Accessibility Services.

Comment: When you ask Android related questions, you should always include Android Version, TalkBack version, Device, etc.  As there's such a wide variety of behaviors and combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, uedited question to reflect android version and talkback version

Comment: @kyo171 I am facing the same issue at the moment, have you found any solution to this?

Comment: can you please share more code?

Comment: @kyo171 Any updates on this?

Comment: @kyo171 could you solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use announce for accessibility option in this case.
anounceForAccessibility
added in API level 16
public void announceForAccessibility (CharSequence text)
Convenience method for sending a AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT AccessibilityEvent to make an announcement which is related to some sort of a context change for which none of the events representing UI transitions is a good fit. For example, announcing a new page in a book. If accessibility is not enabled this method does nothing.